# How to drop table if model changes in EF4 code first database initializer?

Tags: entity-framework-4, initialization, code-first

I have a modular architecture where some tables are depending on whether the module is installed.  In entity framework CTP4, how can I use a database initialization strategy that drops and recreates a table (rather than entire database) when the model changes?

Answer (score 0):

As of EF CTP4, there is *no way* to "selectively drop tables" instead of recreating the database.

That said, there are a number of new features coming in the final version of EF Code First that will (hopefully) let you achieve what you are looking for like the ability to write your own custom SQL scripts when overriding *Seed* method in your initializer or *[Code First Database Evolution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/22/code-first-database-evolution-aka-migrations.aspx)* feature that the team is currently working on which will evolve the database schema as your object model changes over time instead of recreating it.